# How to make this script 'bulletproof'

Tags: javascript, jquery, demandware

I have a script that is failing when calling 'box-tip' [0] index. is there a way to improve/fix this script or make it more bulletproof so that it doesn't break? all suggestions welcome, please view my code below.

```js
var map = {};

var site = util.getCookie('CTCountry').toLowerCase();
if (site === 'gb' || site === 'us' || site === 'xbr' || site === 'eu') {
  map = {
    '14.5': 33,
    '15': 33,
    '15.5': 34,
    '16': 35,
    '16.5': 35,
    '17': 35,
    '17.5': 36,
    '18': 36,
    '19': 37,
    '20': 37
  };
} else {
  map = {
    '37': 84,
    '38': 84,
    '39': 86,
    '41': 86,
    '42': 89,
    '43': 89,
    '44': 91,
    '46': 91,
    '48': 94,
    '50': 94
  };
}

function applyRecommendedSleeveLength(selectedVal) {
  if (selectedVal !== undefined) {
    var recommendedVal = map[selectedVal.trim()];
    var selected = $('.attribute__swatch--selected:first div').text().trim();
    if (recommendedVal === null || recommendedVal === undefined) {
      selectedVal = $('.attribute__swatch--selected:first div').text().trim();
      recommendedVal = map[selectedVal.trim()];
    }
    var sleevSwatches = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="attribute__swatch--length-"] div');
    sleevSwatches.forEach(function(swatch, i) {
      $('showBorder').removeClass('info');
      swatch.classList.remove('showBorder');
      $('.box-tip').hide();
    });

    if (selected === null || selected === '' || selected === undefined) return;

    var recommendedLis = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="attribute__swatch--length-' + recommendedVal + '"] div');
    recommendedLis.forEach(function(recommendedLi, i) {
      if (recommendedLi !== null && recommendedLi !== undefined) {
        recommendedLi.classList.add('showBorder');
        $('.box-tip').show();
        var currentPosition = $('.showBorder').parent().position().left;
        var info = document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip')[0];
        if (info !== null && info !== undefined) {
          info.style.paddingLeft = currentPosition + -75 + 'px';
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

(function() {
  if (typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach === "function") return false;
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
})();
```

Comment: Ugh.  Your snippet doesn't work (because that's not HTML, it's some server-side templating thing).  So no way to know what the page looks like as is, and not a very concrete question or error message.  If you could provide rendered html such that when someone clicks "Run code snippet" they are able to see the problem you're having that would be wonderful.

Comment: @James i have edited the question. sorry to make myself clearer i want to be able to make the script more bulletproof so if something doesn't run there is a full back option for example if box-tip is not found the page will not break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for box-tip:

```
var info = document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip')[0];
```

This will break if there are no elements with `class='box-tip'` because you are forcing it to read the first element of that collection even though there might be none.  That can be quickly repaired as:

```
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip');
var info = collection.length ? collection[0] : false;
// if there were no elements in the collection info = false;

if (info) {
  info.style.paddingLeft = currentPosition + -75 + 'px' ;
}
```